# Regular expression to allow a set of characters that are repeated different times

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new on regex and for learning purpose, i'm coding a word finding program. It takes a pool of characters and when i press "find" button, it lists all possible words from that character set. Looping in word list, the program compares each word with regex pattern.

Inside that, i wrote a simple pattern to make it work. for example:

```
^[mase]+$
```

but it doesn't work properly.

---

**brief explation and what i try to achieve, with one example below :**

if the char pool is ahbbhhh then i want to match words which contain a minimum of one a, h, or b AND a maximum of 1 a, 4 h's, and 2 b's. it shouldn't contain any other characters.

Comment: You can add those `char`s to a `HashSet<char>` and then get the `char`s from there, so they won't be repeated.

Comment: Have you tried using what you already have with the repeated characters - it seems like it would already match them (unless I misunderstand your goal)

Comment: Oh you are you trying to ensure your regex pattern does not match examples with repeated chars?

Comment: `[maasssse]` matches any of `mase`. If you want to match `aa` and/or `ssss`, you could try `^(?:m|aa|ssss|e)+$`

Comment: Duplicate characters within a character set are redundant. `[maasssse]` is logically identical to `[mase]`. Regex is not designed to generate output; it's made for matching input. I don't think it makes sense to use regex for what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @egnomerator I edited my question to be more clearer. can you check it?

Comment: @SGKoishi That solves part of my problem, but i also need words with lesser repeats like (mase, maase)... to be more clear, i edited question. can u check it?

Comment: @CAustin added a case to be more clear. Can you check?

Comment: So if the char pool is `ahbbhhh` then you want to match words which contain a minimum of one `a`, `h`, or `b` AND a maximum of 1 `a`, 4 `h`s, and 2 `b`s?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes, exactly this! can you help me?

Comment: You should edit your post and use my explanation at the very beginning so that people can stop guessing wrong answers.

Comment: Should the results be limited to words which only contain those chars as well?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes, it should be limited like this.

Comment: This cannot be done with pure regex. You will need to parse the user's input, make note of char limits, loop through the char limits, and check for words which match the criteria.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, i will try to do that.

Comment: One idea for ignoring words which contain non-char-pool chars would be to use `^[ahc]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think RegEx would support this.
However its a simple test on any programming language.
Here is an example on C#:

```
private Dictionary<char, int> WordToChars(string word)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (var c in word)
    {
        if (result.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            result[c] += result[c] + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            result[c] = 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private bool DoesMatchPattern(string patternString, string testString)
{
    var pattern = WordToChars(patternString);
    var test = WordToChars(testString);

    return test.All(x => pattern.TryGetValue(x.Key, out int qty) && qty >= x.Value);
}
```

In few words: WordToChar() converts any string to characters with repeated quantities.
And DoesMatchPattern() compares that test string has only chars found in pattern string and corresponding repeated qty is less or equal to the pattern.